# Chromebook to Linux Beta to using it for live streaming on twitch?

Tags: linux, streaming, chromebook, twitch

I have a Acer N17Q8 Chromebook Spin 11 and i turned on Linux Beta but doesn't seem to have access to sudo nor shell due to error messages in crosh. Any guidelines i should follow on? And i'm actually avoiding developer mode because it deletes the data i already have in my chromebook that i would rather keep. I actually wanted to use my chromebook to go live streaming with twitch while i'm slowly building my gaming pc. I don't have an android and i don't use linux and android apps since i'm mostly playing and streaming on my PS4 and Steam.

Answer (score 0):

Crostini has a separate terminal in your Everything menu. The shell you are talking about is for something like crouton, which requires dev mode.